# Can I put a CC BY-SA photo in a non CC BY-SA work?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons, photographs

Assuming there are [no copyright restrictions on the subject](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/is-it-legal-to-publish-under-cc-by-sa-a-picture-of-a-recent-sculpture-in-japan), can I insert a CC BY-SA photo as a figure in another work, for example an academic paper, that is not itself CC BY-SA?

(Somewhere along the line I picked up this idea that CC BY-SA is more like LGPL than GPL when it comes to inclusion in other works. If so, is the difference between inclusion and modification clearcut?)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you comply with the license as regards attribution and labelling (ie, you indicate the author + the license in an appropriate way, such as an image caption) then you are free to do this.

The CC license [distinguishes](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/legalcode) between "derivative works"(1a), which need to get the CC-BY-SA license, and "collective works" (1c), which don't. Including one CC-BY-SA paper as a chapter in a book is considered a collective work, for example, and including an otherwise unmodified picture as a figure in a paper would seem to fall easily under this definition.

---

**Edit (October 2015):** a US district court has [recently discussed](http://www.technollama.co.uk/us-court-interprets-copyleft-clause-in-creative-commons-licenses) a similar issue (a CC-BY-SA image being used as the cover of a book) and held that that situation clearly constitutes a "collective work":

> Because this 112-page book of maps is not in any way "based upon"” the Photograph, and because defendant did not "recast, transform[], or adapt[]" the Photograph when it used it as the cover art for the Atlas, see License § 1(b), the Court finds that neither the Atlas nor its cover constitutes a derivative work subject to the ShareAlike requirement. Rather, the Atlas is more akin to a collective work, because the Photograph was placed "in its entirety in unmodified form" alongside "other contributions, constituting separate and independent works" – that is, the maps."